# One liner solution to sort an associative array in ascending order keeping the original keys but push empty arrays at the end of resultant array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an associative array with `current_price` in it. Some of array indexes are empty.

I want to sort it by current_price index. But here is twist, I want to have arrays not having current_price index to the end of array.

With this code.

```
uksort($lowest_prices, function ($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a->current_price , $b->current_price ); });
```

This gives me this result.

```
(
    [www.website1.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here          

        )

    [www.website2.com] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product Name here
            [current_price] => 79.99                
        )

    [www.website3.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 89.99          
        )

    [www.website4.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 99.89          
        )

    [www.website5.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 99.99         
        )
)
```

I also tried

```
usort($lowest_prices, function ($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a->current_price) && isset($b->current_price)) {
        return strnatcmp($a->current_price, $b->current_price);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This gives me this result.

```
(

    [www.website2.com] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Product Name here
            [current_price] => 79.99                
        )

    [www.website3.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 89.99          
        )

    [www.website4.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 99.89          
        )

    [www.website1.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here          

        )
    [www.website5.com] => stdClass Object
        (           
            [name] => Product Name here           
            [current_price] => 99.99         
        )
)
```

I want all of arrays not having `current_price` index to be at the end of array.

Comment: try returning -1 in your else for your second example

Comment: @cmorrissey that puts empty array at top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
uasort($lowest_prices, function ($a, $b) {
    if (isset($a->current_price) && isset($b->current_price)) {
        return strnatcmp($a->current_price, $b->current_price);
    } else {
        //one of the prices is not set, find out which one and sort accordingly
        if(isset($a->current_price)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

this way if both elements have a price, it is sorted by strnatcmp,
otherwise you check if first element has a price and second does not, the first element should be sorted before the second (return -1).
if first element does not have the price set, it will bubble down in the sorting.

Note: when sorting multiple elements with undefined prices, the sort order is unpredictable. If you want for example to sort the ones without the price on some other parameter you should then use sth like

```
if(!isset($a->current_price) && !isset($b->current_price)) {
    //return comparisson of some other parameter
    return strnatcmp($a->name, $b->name);
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works, but how do I keep array indexes? Your code removes my array indexes for example `[www.website2.com]`

Comment: I did it with `uasort` ... I will test your code with more data and will accept your answer.

Comment: I added some more explanation about the sorting within all the elements without the price. Don't know if that is important for you or not rly :)
will update the code to use uasort, forgot to change that when copying from your snippet.